# why the second new failure cannot invoke the override delete?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        throw "error";//throw exception deliberately
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr, string msg) { // 0
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr) { // 1
        cout << "no msg" << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    try {
        Test* t0 = new Test; // print “no msg”
        Test* t1 = static_cast<Test*>(::operator new(sizeof Test)); // no print
    }
    catch(...){}
}
```

I'm wondering is there any difference between the first new and second new? I ctrl+lclicked the mouse and was navigated to the same declaration of new in vcruntime_new.h, but the result of the code above shows that they are not really the same one or is there anything I don't know?

Comment: The constructor isn't called in the second one.

Comment: consequently there is no object of type `Test` at the returned address so casting it to `Test*` is wrong.

Comment: Thank you!
Is ::operator new not the normal new? Is there any difference between them?